# How to exclude a class with Swift Error Breakpoint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exception, breakpoints

If I set a default Swift Error Breakpoint it hits on every error, I'd like to know if it's possible to exclude a class so that it would be skipped

For instance how can I exclude class `ViewController` and exceptions thrown with `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` in case of malformed JSON

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(isValidJSON(jsonString: "test"))
    }
    
    func isValidJSON(jsonString:String) -> Bool {
        var res = false
        let json = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        do{
            if try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] != nil{
                res =  true
            }
            else if try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]] != nil {
                res =  true
            }
        }
        catch {
            let e = error as NSError
            print(e.localizedDescription, e.code)
            
        }
        return res
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work if you type `((SEL)$arg2 != "jsonObject(with:options:)") && ((ViewController)$arg0 != nil)"` in the breakpoint condition for disabling `jsonObject` raises and view controller ?

Comment: @PranavKasetti no, this gives me error `Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 1.1: "(SEL)$arg2 != "jsonObject(with:options:)""
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
warning: <user expression 0>:1:12: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)
(SEL)$arg2 != "jsonObject(with:options:)"`